# SQL state: 42883, No function matches the given name and argument types. But that function actually exists

Tags: postgresql, function, casting, search-path

I have a server with PostgreSQL 8.1.23, with a function that works perfectly when it runs with `postgres` user, but with another user shows the SQL STATE:

> ```
> SQL state: 42883
> ```

This is my function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fun_validatepost(integer, integer)
  RETURNS integer AS
$BODY$
...
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
ALTER FUNCTION fun_validatepost(integer, integer)
  OWNER TO postgres;
GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTION fun_validatepost(integer, integer) TO public;
GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTION fun_validatepost(integer, integer) TO postgres;
GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTION fun_validatepost(integer, integer) TO someuser;
```

If I run this with postgres user like this:

```
select fun_validatepost(1,230465);
```

The result is like this:

```
-[ RECORD 1 ]-----------+--
fun_validatepost        | 1
```

But if I execute the same query as someuser, shows me this message:

> ```
> ERROR:  function fun_validatepost(integer, integer) does not exist
> SQL state: 42883
> HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You may need to add explicit type casts
> ```

Even if a do a explicit cast I get the same result:

```
select fun_validatepost from fun_validatepost(1::integer,230465::integer);
```

Same error message.

What can I do so `someuser` can execute the same function?
Is there something wrong with my function or cast?

Comment: 8.1 was release about 6 or 7 years ago.

Comment: 8.1 was actually released in 2005. Last updated about 6 or 7 years ago.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most probably a matter of schema vs. schema `search_path`. The function is created in the default schema of the creating user. If that's not in the `search_path` of the current user, it's not visible.

Details:

- [How does the search_path influence identifier resolution and the "current schema"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9067335/how-does-the-search-path-influence-identifier-resolution-and-the-current-schema/9067777#9067777)

Typically, you would create public functions in the schema `public` and have that schema in everbody's `search_path`.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.fun_validatepost(integer, integer)
  RETURNS integer AS
$BODY$
...
$BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
ALTER FUNCTION public.fun_validatepost(integer, integer) OWNER TO postgres;
```

Schema-qualification is only needed if `public` isn't the default schema anyway.

Also, your `GRANT` commands make no sense. The `EXECUTE` privilege for functions is granted to `public` by default. And once you grant to `public`, there is no need to grant to other users. Especially not to `postgres`, which is the `OWNER` anyway and a superuser, too. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-grant.html)

> PostgreSQL grants default privileges on some types of objects to
> `PUBLIC`. [...] `EXECUTE` privilege for functions;

You do need to grant `USAGE` on the `SCHEMA` where the function is created. The `public` schema grants `USAGE` to `public` (everyone) by default.

Aside 1

Casting to `integer` does not change anything here because a numeric literal without decimal point is coerced to integer automatically. [Details about constants in the manual.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS)

Aside 2

[Urgently consider updating to a current version of Postgres. Your software is completely outdated.](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)

Comment: thank you, actually the problem was solved with a GRANT USAGE statement.